# I need to retrieve a Rating class object. Joincolums values cannot be retrieve. How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to retrieve a Ratings class object. But userId and answer_id are foreign keys. Therefore they are join Columns.

```
  @Query("SELECT r FROM Ratings r WHERE r.userId = ?1 AND r.answer_id = ?2")
    public Ratings searchObject(Long userId,Long answerId);
```

```
public class Ratings {
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    private Answer answer;
//GETTERS AND SETTETRS
}
```

This error has occurred. when I tried to retrieve ratings object:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
> userId of: com.smartedulanka.finalyearproject.datalayer.entity.Ratings

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if you want to use a HQL (recommended) or a native query:

- HQL:

  ```
  @Query("FROM Ratings r WHERE r.user.id = ?1 AND r.answer.id = ?2")
  ```
- SQL:

  ```
  @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Ratings r WHERE r.userId = ?1 AND r.answer_id = ?2")
  ```

Comment: Thank you. @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Ratings r WHERE r.userId = ?1 AND r.answer_id = ?2") In this case i had to use 8 instead of r